# Nested child components undefined input properties

Tags: angular

I have a component that has `dataModel` as an Input, the `dataModel` is undefined when the constructor is called.

```
<div class="container">
    <dataViewer [dataModel]="data"></dataViewer>
</div>
```

**Component**

```
@Input() dataModel: DataModel;

// ..

constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
   this.htmlElement = this.element.nativeElement;
   this.selectorElement = d3.select(this.element.nativeElement);

   if (this.dataModel== undefined) { throw 'dataModel is undefined' };

}
```

The parent component has a route resolver, how can I ensure the `dataModel` is set when the `dataViewer` component is constructed? Could I delay the construction of any child components to ensure it is not undefined?

```
this.route.data
            .subscribe(( data: { foo: Bar[] }) => {
                self.foo = foo;
            });
```

Comment: Is the parent component initializing the dataModel?  If not how is it get initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider moving the code from the constructor to the ngOnChanges event of the nested component. That event will occur when the dataModel property is set or changed.

You'll still need an if around the code to ensure you don't see an undefined when the component is first loaded.